# Trasfering Userform data automatically into next blank row

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have tried to find out where I am going wrong but not successful.

I am able to capture data from userform when I click on <kbd>submit</kbd> button and this data is transferred to first row of Excel sheet. But when I clear the userform and trying to enter new data and click on <kbd>submit</kbd> button it is transferring the new data onto the old data (first row) it is not moving to second row automatically.

I have checked all possibilities please help me where I am doing mistake in my code.

Below is the Code for the submit button.

```html
Private Sub btnsave_Click()


Dim WB As Workbook
Dim ssheet as Worksheet

Set WB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Gateways.xlsx")
Set ssheet = WB.Worksheets("Proc")

Dim nr As Integer
nr = ssheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'keep a count of the ID for later use Loop

'Populate the new data values into the 'Data' worksheet 'Next ID number

ssheet.Cells(nr, 3) = Me.cmbls
ssheet.Cells(nr, 4) = Me.tbProject
ssheet.Cells(nr, 5) = Me.cmbbase
 If cmbbase.Value = "" Then
 
      MsgBox "You must complete base", vbCritical
      Exit Sub
 
  End If

ssheet.Cells(nr, 6) = Me.tbenovia
  If tbenovia.Value = "" Then
 
      MsgBox "You must complete Enovia no", vbCritical
      Exit Sub
 
  End If

ssheet.Cells(nr, 7) = Me.tbaxalant
ssheet.Cells(nr, 8) = Me.tbmaterial
ssheet.Cells(nr, 9) = Me.tbpart
ssheet.Cells(nr, 10) = Me.tbrequest
ssheet.Cells(nr, 11) = Me.cmbtask1
ssheet.Cells(nr, 12) = Me.cmbdetail1
ssheet.Cells(nr, 13) = Me.tbdetail2
ssheet.Cells(nr, 14) = Me.tbtools
ssheet.Cells(nr, 18) = Me.cmblocation
ssheet.Cells(nr, 19) = Me.tbadd
ssheet.Cells(nr, 15) = Me.cmburgent
ssheet.Cells(nr, 2) = CDate(DTPicker1)
ssheet.Cells(nr, 17) = CDate(DTPicker2)
ssheet.Cells(nr, 20) = CDate(DTPicker3)
If radioyes = True Then
    ssheet.Cells(nr, 16) = "Yes"
Else
    ssheet.Cells(nr, 16) = "No"
End If
ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: I have just tested your code and it is working fine for me, if I manually clear the form and enter new data and submit, it will populate a new row. Do you have any other code attached to the form? how are you clearing the form data which then causes the issue when you submit new data? Also you have a couple of message boxes "You must complete...." by the time these checks are carried out you already have data placed on to the sheet: cmbls, tbProject, cmbbase.

Comment: I am using this Code for Clearing the old data in the userform  Dim ctl As MSForms.Control
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        Select Case TypeName(ctl)
            Case "TextBox"
                ctl.Text = ""
            Case "CheckBox", "OptionButton", "ToggleButton"
                ctl.Value = False
            Case "ComboBox", "ListBox"
                ctl.ListIndex = -1

Comment: And may i know is it necessary to use the same worksheet Name "ssheet" in my whole Code or can i Change the sheet Name as mentioned below for the Combobox  Private Sub cmbls_DropButtonClick()

Dim WB As Workbook
Set WB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Gateways.xlsx")
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = WB.Worksheets("Process2")
Dim i As Long
If Me.cmbls.ListCount = 0 Then
    For i = 2 To ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Me.cmbls.AddItem Sheets("Process2").Cells(i, "A").Value
    Next i
End If
End Sub

Comment: Please edit your original question and add your code that you use for clearing the form. As for your second question/comment, you will need to ask it as an entirely new question and not add it as a comment or an addition to this question.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, my Problem is not Clearing the form but to make the Input data in the userform should automatically move to next rows.

Comment: As in my first comment, I could not find any problems when I ran your code, each submitted form created a new row of data without over writing previous data. Have you tried replicating the issue by creating a new workbooks and adding the form and code to the new workbook, test and see if the issue happens again. Also it would be useful to know what version of excel and operating system.

Comment: Thanks, i will try with new workbook as suggested by you. My Operating System is Windows 10 and Excel 2016 Version.

Comment: Now i tried as you suggested in a new workbokk but also I ma facing the same Problem. When I enter new data it is going into same row but not going to next row.